# Add UIActivityViewController top most window in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

How to add UIActivityViewController in to top most window.

```
UIActivityViewController *activity=[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"test" ] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: My suggestion is to hide the popup once share button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

vikramarkaios,

You can always use rootViewController property,

```
    UIActivityViewController *activity=[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"test" ] applicationActivities:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject.rootViewController presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will show the alert on all otherViews :)

**EDIT**

As per your editted question here is my answer which I tested and works fine :)

```
 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Public Stock Report" message:NSLocalizedString(@"Your stock report...", nil) preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        //do whatever you want
    }];
    UIAlertAction *settingsAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        UIActivityViewController *activity=[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"test" ] applicationActivities:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:settingsAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i am showing one popup in the view. In pop contains two buttons then one is cancel and another one is share option. once i am click on share button it will comes behind the popup view

Comment: @vikramarkaios : I have updated my answer to consider multiple windows you can try it out :)

Comment: showing activity view controller when the pop up is still present isn't great idea :) When user taps on the butoton first dismiss  the pop up and in its completion block present the activityViewController :)

Comment: i upadate Check once my requirement

Comment: @vikramarkaios : Not sure how are you displaying the alert but I tried using UIAlertController and worked absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Upon clicking the **share** button, dismiss your view properly so that the UIActivityViewController will be the top most presented view. Or better yet, present the UIActivityViewController in your current top most presented view. I hope this makes sense.